# Reversing elements of a string delimited by spaces returns a larger string than the original

Tags: c++, string, substring, reverse

Having fun in c++ on CodeWars trying to reverse the letters of the words in a string, words delimited by spaces ie. "Hello my friend" --> "olleH ym dneirf", where extra spaces are not lost.

My answer is failing the tests, but when I diff my answer and the suggested answer there is no output. I also tried checking the length of the original and reversed strings and there is a significant difference in their lengths, depending on the string. However, when I compare the outputs they are again identical in terms of length, and there is no trailing whitespace.

```
int main() {

    std::string s("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");

    std::cout <<"Old: "<<s<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"New: "<<reverse(s)<<std::endl;

    //lengths are not the same
    std::cout <<"Length of s: "<<s.length()<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Length of reverse(s): "<<reverse(s).length()<<std::endl;

    //check for trailing whitespace
    std::cout <<"Last 5 chars of reverse(s): "<<reverse(s).substr(reverse(s).length() - 6)<<std::endl;
}
```

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) {

    std::string word;
    std::string revWord;
    std::string result;
    char space(' ');

    int cursor = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        std::string revWord;
        if (str[i] == space || i == str.length() - 1){
            if (i == str.length() - 1)
                i++;
            word = str.substr(cursor, i - cursor);
            for(int j = word.length(); j >= 0; j--){
                revWord.push_back(word[j]);
            }
            word = revWord;
            if(i != str.length() - 1)
                result.append(word + " ");
            cursor = i+1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Console Output:

```
Old: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
New: ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god 
Length of s: 44
Length of reverse(s): 54
Last 5 chars of reverse(s): .god
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're doubling up characters between words. Fwiw, you're also including the terminator in your calculation. That console output is *not* what I see. I see: `New:  ehT  kciuq  nworb  xof  spmuj  revo  eht  yzal  .god` , and note the leading space, and double spaces between words. Any particular reason you're not just using iterators and `std::reverse` limited to each word ?

Comment: Those are not spaces but `\0`. However my terminal displays them as spaces too.

Comment: Mentioned in my prior comment, [something like this](https://pastebin.com/pQj62BPD). A bit of a hack. To do it right would involve `std::find` and `std::isspace`, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely ending up with unprintable 'characters' in your string since you're trying to access off the end of a string.

```cpp
for(int j = word.length(); j >= 0; j--){
    revWord.push_back(word[j]);
}
```

Here you set a variable to be equal to the word length, and then this variable is used to read one byte past the end of the string. The data stored here is a NUL byte, which is there so that the `std::string` can be used to produce a matching C-style string without making a copy of its data.

I believe you're also ending up with a space at the end of your string, adding one more extra character.

Comment: More specific, a `std::string` contains a `\0` at the end so it is compatible with c strings. In the debugger it is clearly visible that before each reversed word there is a `\0`.

Comment: Yeah great point, it's not just any data, but the null terminator of the string. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to implement your `reverse()` function, using the [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) algorithm to modify the original `std::string` object inline and not use any additional `std::string` objects at all:

```cpp
std::string reverse(std::string str)
{
    std::string::size_type word_start = 0, word_end;
    std::string::iterator iter = str.begin();

    do
    {
        word_end = str.find(' ', word_start);
        if (word_end == std::string::npos)
        {
            std::reverse(iter + word_start, str.end());
            break;
        }
        std::reverse(iter + word_start, iter + word_end);
        word_start = str.find_first_not_of(' ', word_end + 1);
    }
    while (word_start != std::string::npos);

    return str;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/RAOKq7)